# Selenium (from Python) hangs if I close my browser window

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium

If I start Selenium from Python and close the browser window, my script hangs the next time I try to get the WebDriver to do something. Note that I'm closing the browser *window* while leaving the browser itself open--I'm on a Mac, and it's possible for the browser (Chrome, in my case) to remain open even without any windows. Here's an example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
time.sleep(5) # Let's say we close Chrome window during this time
print "Trying to open second page"
driver.get("http://www.python.org/")
print "You won't get here if you closed the Chrome window"
```

Ideally I'd like Selenium to either make a new window for me or let me tell that there's no open window and let me create one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what is going to happen.  The browser windows you see are not all able to get talked to by selenium.

Selenium spawns a browser with the w3c component running and able to be talked to.  This is kind of like a mini http server that lives in the web browser, that selenium talks to to click on things and do it's business.  It's called WebDriver.
http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/

When you close the browser opened and interfaced with selenium... you are breaking the socket connections selenium made, and it can not find it.

AFAIK: Selenium is just talking to the webdriver interface of the browser.

Your program would have to look for active browsers, get their memory address, open a new selenium-webdriver and point it at it... this would take a bit of re-writing the selenium source as calling a webdriver now initiates a new browser instance.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a way I can detect that the socket is broken (rather than having my program hang)? Or can `driver.get("http://www.python.org/")` be made to open a new socket rather than waiting for the (now dead) old one?

Comment: That is outside the scope of Selenium, as they like to say.  Having in interactive bot/browser is not the goal of that project, an interface to emulate a person using said browser is.  GL!